# Trying to compute an integral

Tags: integration

I found in a book the following statement without more explanations:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{2 ae^{ik|x|}}{|x|(|x|^2+a^2)^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{4\pi}{a}+2\pi^2ik, \quad a>0, \Im k>0$$ 
Trying to figure out why this is true, I went to spherical coordinates and then used integration by parts:
$$  \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{2 ae^{ik|x|}}{|x|(|x|^2+a^2)^2}\mathrm{d}x=8\pi a \int_{r>0}\frac{re^{ikr}}{(r^2+a^2)^2}\mathrm{d}r=\frac{4\pi}{a}+4\pi ika\int_{r>0}\frac{e^{ikr}}{r^2+a^2}\mathrm{d}r$$
But I'm stuck with this last integral. Does anybody see how to compute it and obtain the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not agree that the formula is exact. Indeed, the formula is equivalent to the identity

$$ \frac{\pi}{2a} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikr}}{r^{2} + a^{2}} \, dr, $$

which is true, up to error $o(1)$, as $k \to 0$. Indeed, its exact form is as follows:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikr}}{r^{2} + a^{2}} \, dr = \frac{\pi}{2a} e^{-ak} + \frac{i}{a} \left\{ \mathrm{Shi}(ak)\cosh (ak) - \mathrm{Chi}(ak) \sinh (ak) \right\}, \quad \Im k \geq 0, $$

where $\mathrm{Shi}(z)$ and $\mathrm{Chi}(z)$ are [hyperbolic sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shi.html) and [hyperbolic cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi.html), resp. For $a$ fixed, its asymptotic expansion at $k = 0$ is

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikr}}{r^{2} + a^{2}} \, dr = \frac{\pi}{2a} - ik \log (ak) - \frac{\pi k}{2} + i(1-\gamma)k + O(k^{2}),$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: It seems indeed that my formula was an approximation, even if it is not crystal clear in my book. How do you actually come up with your exact formula? Do you use any tricky change of variable?

Comment: @Lil, There are many ways to derive this (including ODE method), but among them complex analysis technique is quite directly applicable.